# Javascript Twitch API Json Data

Tags: javascript, json, twitch

The json data is here

```
{


 "streams": [
    {
      "_id": 22748053072,
      "game": "Overwatch",
      "viewers": 11344,
      "created_at": "2016-08-10T00:04:34Z",
      "video_height": 720,
      "average_fps": 60.3225806452,
      "delay": 0,
      "is_playlist": false,
      "_links": {
        "self": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams\/timthetatman"
      },
      "preview": {
        "small": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/previews-ttv\/live_user_timthetatman-80x45.jpg",
        "medium": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/previews-ttv\/live_user_timthetatman-320x180.jpg",
        "large": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/previews-ttv\/live_user_timthetatman-640x360.jpg",
        "template": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/previews-ttv\/live_user_timthetatman-{width}x{height}.jpg"
      },
      "channel": {
        "mature": true,
        "status": "gold genji tonight? no strums tmrw- bach party all day!: dbh.la\/timthetatman",
        "broadcaster_language": "en",
        "display_name": "TimTheTatman",
        "game": "Overwatch",
        "language": "en",
        "_id": 36769016,
        "name": "timthetatman",
        "created_at": "2012-10-08T18:13:50Z",
        "updated_at": "2016-08-10T03:33:20Z",
        "delay": null,
        "logo": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/jtv_user_pictures\/timthetatman-profile_image-35bdf9d7b751789e-300x300.jpeg",
        "banner": null,
        "video_banner": "https:\/\/static-cdn.jtvnw.net\/jtv_user_pictures\/timthetatman-channel_offline_image-f4e88d4e35841793-1920x1080.png",
        "background": null,
        "profile_banner": null,
        "profile_banner_background_color": null,
        "partner": true,
        "url": "https:\/\/www.twitch.tv\/timthetatman",
        "views": 27956760,
        "followers": 743104,
        "_links": {
          "self": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman",
          "follows": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/follows",
          "commercial": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/commercial",
          "stream_key": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/stream_key",
          "chat": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/chat\/timthetatman",
          "features": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/features",
          "subscriptions": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/subscriptions",
          "editors": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/editors",
          "teams": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/teams",
          "videos": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/channels\/timthetatman\/videos"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "_total": 1,
  "_links": {
    "self": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams?channel=timthetatman&limit=25&offset=0",
    "next": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams?channel=timthetatman&limit=25&offset=25",
    "featured": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams\/featured",
    "summary": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams\/summary",
    "followed": "https:\/\/api.twitch.tv\/kraken\/streams\/followed"
  }
}
```

When I convert that to an object and do something like
`"streamData.streams.game"` it gives me an error, and when I look in a json viewer it seems like streams is an an array, because it has a 0 by it, however I'm not sure how I can select the right one. I'm so stuck on this, I have no idea how to select any values in streams.

Comment: Can't you use a loop? Or if you know the index just access it directly `streamData.streams[0].game`

Comment: Yes, streams is an array. JSON is literally "Javascript object notation", and you can see the opening `[` after `"streams":`

Comment: I guess top two posts already explained. streams is an array. you have to fetch it like streamsData.streams[i].game where 'i' could be be any value between array length. This is the most basic fundamental! One vote down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the streams field is an array.

To access elements of an array, you simply do `arrayName[elementNumber]`. In the example you provided, the array only has 1 entry, so you can simply do `streamData.streams[0].game`. That will select the first (and only) element in the streams array and return it's game field.

Comment: Oh okay, I was trying to do streamData.streams.0.game, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

streamData.streams is an array not an object, so you've to access it like:

```
streamsData.streams[i].game
```

If you're sure that there will be only 1 object in your array then you can access it like

```
streamsData.streams[0].game
```

**Output**

```
Overwatch
```

**Working Code**

```js
var streamData = JSON.parse('{"streams":[{"_id":22748053072,"game":"Overwatch","viewers":11344,"created_at":"2016-08-10T00:04:34Z","video_height":720,"average_fps":60.3225806452,"delay":0,"is_playlist":false,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/timthetatman"},"preview":{"small":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_timthetatman-80x45.jpg","medium":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_timthetatman-320x180.jpg","large":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_timthetatman-640x360.jpg","template":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_timthetatman-{width}x{height}.jpg"},"channel":{"mature":true,"status":"gold genji tonight? no strums tmrw- bach party all day!: dbh.la/timthetatman","broadcaster_language":"en","display_name":"TimTheTatman","game":"Overwatch","language":"en","_id":36769016,"name":"timthetatman","created_at":"2012-10-08T18:13:50Z","updated_at":"2016-08-10T03:33:20Z","delay":null,"logo":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/timthetatman-profile_image-35bdf9d7b751789e-300x300.jpeg","banner":null,"video_banner":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/timthetatman-channel_offline_image-f4e88d4e35841793-1920x1080.png","background":null,"profile_banner":null,"profile_banner_background_color":null,"partner":true,"url":"https://www.twitch.tv/timthetatman","views":27956760,"followers":743104,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman","follows":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/follows","commercial":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/commercial","stream_key":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/stream_key","chat":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/timthetatman","features":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/features","subscriptions":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/subscriptions","editors":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/editors","teams":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/teams","videos":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/timthetatman/videos"}}}],"_total":1,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=timthetatman\u0026limit=25\u0026offset=0","next":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=timthetatman\u0026limit=25\u0026offset=25","featured":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/featured","summary":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/summary","followed":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/followed"}}');

document.write(streamData.streams[0].game);
```